# Missing Assembly Reference

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Im getting an error : "The type or namespace name 'UnZipper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" , what would be the possible reasons?..which reference i've to add??

Comment: Where does `UnZipper` come from?

Comment: It's related to project. You need to share more info about what are you trying to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of it, UnZipper is a part of a 3rd party library (zlibnet), and you'd have to add a reference to it. In your Solution Explorer, did you right click on References, and add the zlibnet dll?

The dll will be called one of zlib32.dll or zlib64.dll depending on your architecture. If you don't have it already, you can download it from http://zlibnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58643

Comment: yup, i did, bt didnt find any UnZipper dll in add reference...which dll am i supposed to attach?

Comment: sorry, just realized that you _were_ using the zlibnet library, so I edited my answer

Comment: You can download it from the link I've added in my answer then. Once you do, add a reference to it in your project, and it should work.

Comment: If ders any alternativ solns den do inform..coz im unable to download it due to some restrictions..

Comment: Why can't you download it? You can look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx but from what I know, it only works if there's only 1 file that has been zipped